# What is the best way to define and receive post variables for my sortables controller?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a little project I'm working on that involves cakephp and sortables.

Here is the pastebin for one of the three sortables:

http://pastebin.com/YfPQcjVC

What's the best way to receive the variables and change my db (for reference the field name for the particular sortable is boxid where as the item's is just id)

What should the function look like that receives those two variables and updates the DB - I don't want to use this->model->query as that seems inefficient and bypasses the point of cakes structure right?

Any and all help's appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna get some data in controller like

```
if(!empty($this->data['item'])){
  // do something with this $this->data['item']
}
```

you have to use

```
$.post('items/changebox/',{'data[item]':box});
```

not sure that that what you are looking for, but, it's better than

```
$.post('items/changebox/',item+'='+box);
```